# AWS dynamodb ''The provided key element does not match the schema" on getitem

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get items from my dynamodb but i fails.

Tried to find any examples but all seens to give me the same issue, tried others topics but none are php.

```
    $response = $clientDB->getItem([
        'TableName' => 'mytable',
        "ConsistentRead" => true,
        'Key' => [
            'deviceId' => ['S' => 'mydata']
        ]
    ]);
```

When i execute, it brings:

```
The provided key element does not match the schema - {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"The provided key element does not match the schema"}
```

I checked my dynamodb and my key is the deviceId:

[image: Dynamodb getitem problem schema]

When i scan the 'mytable', it brings all values normaly.

Am i missing something?

Comment: You also need to provide the sort key.

Comment: It worked, thnx

Comment: can u add it as awsner to close the question?

Comment: There can be two possible problem as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74920333/12326605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DynamoDB every table needs a [primary key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html). When you have a partition key and a sort key, you create a composite key. In order to get a table item, you need to provide the full primary key, i.e. both the partition and the sort key.