# DynamoDB getItem PHP Issue

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Not sure, what is the issue while get item from DynamoDB.

Json View of Data :

```
{
 "section_id": "6177d23bb5f04ca363fe3d91",
 "chapter_id": "6177ccd4b5f04ca363fe3d63",
 "data": {
 }
}
```

PHP Code :

```
    $sdk = $this->sdk();
    $dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();

    $result = $dynamodb->getItem(
        array(
            'TableName' => 'sections',
            'Key'   => array(
                'section_id'   => array(
                    'S' => '6177d23bb5f04ca363fe3d91'
                )
            )
        )
    );
    print_r($result);
    exit;
```

Error I'm getting

```
Type: Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException
Message: Error executing "GetItem" on "https://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"The provided key element does not match the schema" (truncated...) ValidationException (client): The provided key element does not match the schema - {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"The provided key element does not match the schema"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the error, There could be two possible problems here:

1. You are only providing half of your primary key. For the primary
   key, you must provide all of the attributes. For example, with a
   simple primary key, you only need to provide a value for the
   partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide values
   for both the partition key and the sort key.
2. Field's value should have a proper data type as per the table. It is
   always better to double-check the data type of the value being
   passed. Maybe, you have defined the primary key as a Number and you are
   passing a string value in the getItem call.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells the problem: "The provided key element does not match the schema"

Is section_id your primary key? If so, you can try it like this:

```
$result = $dynamodb->getItem(
    [
        'TableName' => 'sections',
        'Key' => [
            'section_id' => ['S' => '6177d23bb5f04ca363fe3d91'],
        ],
    ]
);
```

You are providing an array to a GetItem call but you need to provide a primary key.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html